# Manual offline/installation of SpecFlow

Tags: visual-studio, specflow

Is it possible to manually install, or perform an offline installation of, SpecFlow? I can install the VS plugin for SpecFlow, but it seems the only way to install the SpecFlow dll is online through NuGet.

My team is behind a firewall without internet access so I am curious to know if this is possible.

Any info/suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the VS extrnsion you don't need the NuGet package. However using the Nuget package and adding it your source tree would ensure that specflow tests can be run even on machines without VS such as build servers, and other developers machines that do not have the SpecFlow extension installed.

Also, you can quite easily add a new NuGet source which can be configured to any folder, either locally or on your internal network. So if you can the SpecFlow extension msi into the office, you can also download the NuGet and make it available.